# Is it possible to directly update database by using urls?(not using php)

Tags: database, url

I want to update my database by using urls.

I wonder if making php file which updates db is the only way to update database.

Is it possible to update db by url directly?(not using php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes when the db exposes an url api, e.g. rest api of couchDB.
Actually you can create such an api by yourself for any database.

Comment: Thank you Pavel! :) , I'm using MySQL DB and how about it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the used database. There are databases like neo4j or elasticsearch which offers a REST api.

But you should have to take care that they are not public accessible or implement an access control. Otherwise you are a welcome target (saving database credentials in the client javascript code is also no solution!).

So please only use it when you use this API from an internal network or you can guarantee that nobody could access the required credentials from the public network.